# Multiple assignment from a vector to individual variables

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, compiler-warnings, non-exhaustive-patterns

In my test suite I am frequently writing code such as

```
val Vector(socialSci, humanities, pureSci, pureApplSci) = foo(someValue)
```

`foo` obviously returns a (short) Vector but I'd like to have names for each of the values.  It's not always four items long, but since it's my test suite the correct number is known and I'm perfectly fine with an exception being thrown if there is a length mismatch.

The above code works -- except that I get a compiler error:

```
match may not be exhaustive.
```

Is there a way to get rid of the compiler warning?  I've tried `@nowarn` and `@nocheck` in various positions with no luck.

Alternatively, is there a succinct way to write this so it doesn't cause a warning in the first place?  The solution at [Convert Vector to Tuple scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27164267/convert-vector-to-tuple-scala) looks promising except that reflection isn't available for ScalaJS.

```
def toTuple(seq: Seq[_]): Product = {
  val clz = Class.forName("scala.Tuple" + seq.size)
  clz.getConstructors()(0).newInstance(seq.map(_.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]): _*).asInstanceOf[Product]
}
```

Is there an approach using a builder or something?

### Update:

Thanks to Dmytro Mitin for reminding me to check my compiler options.  Yes, I had completely forgotten about that and had `-Xlint:valpattern` enabled.  Turning that off removes the warning.

That solves my immediate problem.  But as a challenge, is there a way to implement `toTuple` without using reflection?

Comment: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/Jb0A5lWYQHKKoESw0v8T0Q As you can see by default there is no warning. Show your `scalacOptions` switched on.

Comment: It looks like it should be returning a case class instead of a vector

Comment: @DmytroMitin, thanks for the reminder.  You're spot-on, as you can see in my update.  Not sure how to credit you other than with this comment.  Thanks!

Comment: @michaJlS, I'm not returning a case class because the length can vary.  In the main body of my code I process it as a vector.  But in testing I want to look at the attributes of individual elements.  Having them assigned to variables makes that easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch off `-Xlint:valpattern`.

But if you want to keep `-Xlint:valpattern` and switch off the warning `match may not be exhaustive` in this specific place you can use `@unchecked`

```
def foo(): Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3, 4)
val Vector(socialSci, humanities, pureSci, pureApplSci) = foo() : @unchecked
```

If a vector returned by `foo` can be longer than 4 elements you can additionally use vararg pattern

```
val Vector(socialSci, humanities, pureSci, pureApplSci, _*) = ...
```

You can also transform a vector into a tuple with [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless). I can't see direct `Vector => Tuple`, so I'm using `Vector => HList => Tuple`

```
import shapeless.syntax.std.traversable._ // libraryDependencies += "com.chuusai" %% "shapeless" % "2.3.10"
val (socialSci, humanities, pureSci, pureApplSci) = foo().toSizedHList(4).get.tupled
```

On contrary to runtime reflection, this mostly works at compile time (we're specifying `4` statically, otherwise `.get` will throw `java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get` at runtime), so this should work in ScalaJS too

```
libraryDependencies += "com.chuusai" %%% "shapeless" % "2.3.10" // ScalaJS
```